# Mavericks server configuration for Rails app

Tags: osx-server, macos, rails

I have just downloaded OS X Server for Mavericks and now I want to run my Rails app through the server. I have downloaded and installed Passenger. My server runs under `username.no-ip.biz` and my Rails app is in `Users/Username/documents/Developer/Rails/railsapp`. First, how do I add a subdomain for the server like `sub.username.no-ip.biz` and second how do I setup the Server to use this subdomain to run my Rails app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring OS X 10.7 Lion Server to serve Rails Apps via Apache](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/configuring-os-x-10-7-lion-server-to-serve-rails-apps-via-apache)

Comment: Let's wait to see how this question gets edited before closing it as duplicate. 1) Mavericks could be different than Lion. 2) This has two questions and one should be edited out unless they are really two views of one underlying idea / solution.

Comment: I did read the question from this other user, but it doesn't apply to my problem.